# jQuery button for toggling a dropdown Yes/No value for all the rows in a table

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a table which has a (Yes/No) dropdown menu for each row and I want to use a button to change the value of the dropdown to Yes using jQuery.
This is what I was trying:
HTML:

```
<select name="activeFlag">
    <option value="true">Yes</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>
</select> 
<br />
<input type="button" value="Activate All" id="activateAllButton">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            jQuery('#activateAllButton').button();
            $('#activateAllButton').click(
            function() 
            {
                $('select>option:eq(0)').attr('selected', true);
            });
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this code works for you

```
$("#activateAllButton").click(function () {
    $("#myTable td select[name='activeFlag']").val('True');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qHjex/)

Comment: Yup this works, I only used the 'select[name=activeFlag]' though.

Answer (score 3):

Just make the click handler:

```
$('#activateAllButton').click(function() {
    $('select').val('true');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZP9dY/)**

Comment: Thanks, I did have to use the name though as Stefan suggested!

Comment: Yes, if you have more than one select than you'd have to be more specific than just `$('select')`.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than `.attr()`, use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

```
$(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            jQuery('#activateAllButton').button();
            $('#activateAllButton').click(
            function() 
            {
                $('select>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
            });
        });
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/UKKKR/1/

Answer (score 1):

The other 2 answers are both right, but I just wanted to show a more efficient version that uses caching:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var $buttons = $('#activateAllButton'),
        $select = $('select');

    $buttons.button().on('click', function () 
    {
        $select.val('true');
    });
});
```

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/N9KBw/)***